# 2005 PT Cruiser Emissions Light On Periodically

Tags: emissions

The emissions light comes on and while driving, it starts to jerk as if driving a standard transmission and not using the clutch properly. Take my foot of the gas pedal & it will stop for a few minutes - then I can accelerate no problem. Also, I could be driving about 90-110 km/hr and it will start to jerk and loose power. It is very frustrating - I changed gas and also put on a new gas cap tightening it as much as possible. I need some help.

Comment: We need the codes. Please see [Something's wrong with my vehicle and there's a Check Engine Light. What information do I need to provide?](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/1473/675)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, codes would help. That said, to me this sounds like misfire. Usually, in such cases the engine light will actually blink (meaning you should not drive the car prior to repair the issue).